# System environment variables in cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, cmd, windows-xp

I am trying to create an environment variable for a specific user profile whilst using the command line (cmd.exe). I know of the `setx` command but cannot create a variable for a user. So my goal is to create an environment variable that is user specific aimed to the mapped network drive letter "M:". Anyway?

Comment: If we start with a manual configuration, can you tell us what is the expected output in the environment variable then we can script it using **SetX** command line

Answer (score 1):

`setx` cannot create environment variables for **other** users (though it can create user-scoped variables), and it sends the `WM_SETTINGSCHANGE` message to notify running processes that the environment has changed.

User-scoped environment variables are just registry values, stored under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`. You can create one for a given profile by modifying the value/data pairs under that key. Modifying the registry doesn't send the `WM_SETTINGSCHANGE`, like `setx` does, though.

#### User Profile Exists

You can create a variable for a specific user (whose profile already exists) by loading the registry hive

```
reg load HKU\ForeignUser C:\Users\<userid>\NTUSER.DAT
```

*(The user cannot be logged on or have been logged on since Windows was booted. `NTUSER.DAT` will be locked in those circumstances.)*

Then you can execute registry-modifying commands relative to that key (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ForeignUser`) to create/modify environment variables.

```
reg add HKU\ForeignUser\Environment /v ENVVAR_NAME /t REG_SZ /d envvar_value
```

#### Default User Profile

If the user has never logged onto the machine, modifying the default user profile will allow you to precreate the environment for *all* new user profiles.

You could modify the default user profile (`HKEY_USERS\.Default\Environment`) to configure environment variables.

```
reg add HKEY_USERS\.Default\Environment /v ENVVAR_NAME /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d envvar_value
```

If you include `%USERNAME%` or some other environment variable in the _envvar_value_, then you could make it work for all users.
This would, however, create the envvar for all subsequent users who log into the machine for the first time. If you only want the variable created for a single user, this is probably not the best solution.

#### Global Script

Alternately, you could create a login script (invoked by creating a value under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`; [description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) that would create the envvar, using `setx` or registry modification commands. If you only wanted it to work for a specific user, you'd have to check the username inside the script, like:

```
IF "%USERNAME%"=="TARGET_USER" SETX ENVVAR_NAME "envvar_value"
```